# How to watch for changes in window.location with Dart?

Tags: dart

I would like to watch for changes in window.location with Dart but haven't found how to do it. Is there an event I can use or some other way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you want when the hash changes, because if window.location is changed it loads a new page. Try this:

```dart
import "dart:html";

window.onHashChange.listen((HashChangeEvent e) {
  //Do stuff
});
window.onPopState.listen((PopStateEvent e) {
  //Do stuff
});
```

PopStateEvent API: http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/PopStateEvent.html

> A popstate event is dispatched to the window every time the active history entry changes between two history entries for the same document. If the history entry being activated was created by a call to history.pushState() or was affected by a call to history.replaceState(), the popstate event's state property contains a copy of the history entry's state object.
>
> > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onpopstate

Comment: Thanks! You could add to the answer that you need to import "dart:html" as well, just to be perfectly clear for anyone reading this later on. :)